# Focus on first input with errors. Problem with this.$refs.array[0]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to focus on first input that have error. I’m using vuelidate.

The problem is with this.$refs.array[index].$el.focus()

Error in console : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

But if I place ref name of input in place of array, everything works!

I have such mixin file

```js
export default {
    async beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
        if (this.isEditSchoolPage || this.isEditMode) {
            if (await this.showSavingDialog()) {

                if (this.$v && this.$v.$invalid) {
                    this.$v.$touch();
                    this.focusFirstError();
                    return;
                }

                await this.submit(true);
            }

            removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.leaveDialog);
        }
        next();
    },

    methods: {
        focusFirstError() {
            var invalidFields = Object.keys(this.$v.$params)
                .filter(fieldName => this.$v[fieldName].$invalid);

            if (invalidFields) {
                this.$refs.invalidFields[0].$el.focus();
                return;
            }
        },
    }
}
```

I placed ref="" in component input

```html
<v-form-group :validator="$v.taxRate" label="Sales Tax Rate (%)" label-required>
    <form-input-formatted type="percent" v-model="taxRate" ref="taxRate"/>
</v-form-group>
```

If I replace

`this.$refs.invalidFields[0].$el.focus();`

With

`this.$refs.taxRate.$el.focus();`

It is working as I expected.

Some images from console.
ibb.co/s36vWBQ

ibb.co/0Jqm9jD

ibb.co/rwfNJ0w

Comment: Can you console your this.$refs.invalidFields and add here?

Comment: https://ibb.co/s36vWBQ
https://ibb.co/0Jqm9jD
https://ibb.co/rwfNJ0w

Comment: You didn't define ref on `<v-form-group>`, so it throw error surely. You can add `<v-form-group ref="invalidFields">`

Comment: I added `<v-form-group ref="taxRate">` but nothing changed

Comment: tried some logging

`console.log(invalidFields[0]);`

returns preferredDays

`console.log(this.$refs.preferredDays);`

return Object

`console.log(this.$refs.invalidFields[0]);`

return error

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
this.$refs[invalidFields[0]].$el.focus();
```